# Kendo Grid - Hide newly added row while editing in Popup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo grid with editable popup and I want to hide/not use the row which is showing editing changes on runtime.

**Reason**:

I have a kendo multiselect control in popup and on saving data it adds multiple rows in db and it should show in grid as well. That's why I don't want to show that editing changes line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
I was looking for a property of Kendo Grid to not show the editing row but didn't found so I removed the first row in edit function of Kendo Grid

```
$("#MyKendoGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: myDataSource,
    //
    // other properties
    //
    edit: function (e) {
        $("#MyKendoGrid .k-grid-content table tr:first").remove();
    }
});
```